# Python paho MQTT loop_forever(): how to redirect output to a file while the script is running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mqtt, paho, python-paho

I'm running a script to subscribe to topics of an MQTT broker and fetch the data associated to them. I run the script like this:

`$ python3 test_mqtt_client.py`

```
import paho.mqtt.client as paho
import ssl
import random

from config import BROKER_ADDRESS, PORT, CLIENT_CERT, CLIENT_KEY, CA_KEY, SUBSCRIBED_TOPICS, DEST_FOLDER

#"on_message" callback
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
  
  print("received message =",str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))


  filename = str(random.randint(0,4294967295))

  file = open(DEST_FOLDER + filename + '.json', 'w+')
  file.write(str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))
  file.close()


client=paho.Client() 
client.on_message=on_message

print("connecting to broker")

client.tls_set(
    CA_KEY,
    certfile=CLIENT_CERT,
    keyfile=CLIENT_KEY,
    cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
    tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2,
    ciphers=None
)

client.tls_insecure_set(True)

client.connect(BROKER_ADDRESS, PORT, 60)

for x in SUBSCRIBED_TOPICS:
  client.subscribe(x)
  print('Subscribed to topic "' + x + '".')

client.loop_forever()

time.sleep(1)
```

The problem: if I try to output to a file like this:

`$ python3 test_mqtt_client.py >> /tmp/test_mqtt_client.log`

I don't get any content on the file *untill* I interrupt the script using Ctrl+C.

How can I get the output of the script inside `/tmp/test_mqtt_client.log` while the script is running? I mean, before interrupting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, output to stdout is *buffered*: that means it's not actually flushed to a file until the output buffer is full, which in turns means that when redirecting stdout to a file, you often won't see anything in the file until your code generates sufficient output to overflow the output buffer.

There are various ways of dealing with with this behavior:

1. Just output to *stderr* instead of *stdout*. *stderr* is not buffered by default and you should see output immediately. This is the  default behavior of e.g. the `logging` module, which is generally a better idea than `print` for logging output from long-running programs. You can, of course, just set `file=sys.stderr` in your `print` command instead:

   ```
   print("this is a test", file=sys.stderr)
   ```

   (If you do this, remember to redirect *stderr* instead of *stdout* on the command line.)
2. You can run Python in unbuffered mode by adding the `-u` flag to the command line:

   ```
   python -u test_mqtt_client.py >> test_mqtt_client.log
   ```
3. You can explicitly flush the output buffer after each `print` statement:

   ```
   print("some log message")
   sys.stdout.flush()
   ```

Comment: Thanks! the "-u" option works.